# No result from a getJSON in cordova

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, cordova

I have some problem with my cordova app. I have a php page with a mini REST service with JSON output and i want to use this result in my app.

Php page:

```
<?
header("Content-Type:application/json");

function response($status, $status_message, $data){
    header("HTTP/1.1 $status $status_message");

    echo $data;
}


$link = mysqli_connect("db4free.net", "luigi", "nzor4csv4", "usl5");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    response(400, "Failed to connect to MySQL", mysqli_connect_error());
}


if( !empty($_GET['prestazioni']) ){
    //make response using database 
    $result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT DISTINCT `ppasez_descrizione` FROM `prestazioni`");

    $arr = array();

    while($obj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $arr[] = $obj;

    }
    $message= json_encode($arr);

    response(200, "lista prestazioni", $message);
} else {
    //invalid request
    response(400, "invalid request", NULL);
}
?>
```

html page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/libs/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mainjs.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.support.cors=true;
            $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
            $("button").click(function(){
                $.getJSON('http://www.****.it/provaluigi/index.php?prestazioni=""',function(data){
                    $.each(data, function(i, dat){
                        $("ul").append("<li>"+dat.ppasez_descrizione+"</li>");  
                    });
                    $('ul').listview('refresh');
                    //if $("list") do $("list").listview("refresh);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <title>
        Prestazioni
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <section id="page1" data-role="page" data-fullscreen="true">
        <div class="content" data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filterplaceholder="cerca prestazione">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

This code work perfect on local domain but i can't see the outcome once inserted in cordova.

As you can see i insert:

```
            $.support.cors=true;
            $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
```

and

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

in config.xml to permit cross domain request.

Also when i test in chrome with "ripple extension" i notice 2 error:

```
Failed to load resource    http://localhost:8383/Centri%20USL/config.xml
```

and.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE     http://localhost:8383/Centri%20USL/cordova.js
```

So probably there are some errors in the linking of cordova package but i use netbeans so it's all automatic. 
Can someone help me find the error?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

According to the [PhoneGap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.0rc1/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide)

> The whitelisting rules are found in res/xml/cordova.xml

Try adding that rule to `res/xml/cordova.xml`

Comment: It may seem strange but in the project folder i don't have "res" folder so i created res/xml/cordova.xml under www folder with the whitelisting but still doesn't work

Comment: Yes. I don't know if it's a problem of netbeans maybe

Answer (score -1):

The error might be caused because you try to access with only `localhost` and no real machine name. Either enter your hostname or the IP address.

That means you need to change `http://localhost:8383/` to something like `http://192.168.1.1:8383/` or `http://fastbox:8383`